# What package should I use to create a diagram in Angular?

Tags: angular, graph, diagram, flowchart

I want to have a diagram for a project that has drag and drop and the user can add a node.
I want to implement something like the image below with Angular9.
Please introduce me to a package of npm that will not be a problem in the next angular updates and can be implemented with Angular.
thank you

[image]

Comment: Can you share what all things did you find on google when looking for a solution ? Such type of questions should also be backed by your findings and issues associated to that

Comment: I found packages like gojs, ngx-graph, ej2, but I don't know if they are expandable or not. And I don't know if these will be a problem in future Angular updates. That's why I asked the question, if anyone knows a package that is powerful and has worked with that package and has not had any problems, introduce me that package.

Answer (score 0):

Try [`@syncfusion/ej2-angular-diagrams'](https://ej2.syncfusion.com/angular/documentation/diagram/getting-started/)

[`NPM`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@syncfusion/ej2-angular-diagrams)

Syncfusion Angular UI (Essential JS 2) is a collection of modern TypeScript based true Angular Components. It has support for Ahead Of Time (AOT) compilation and Tree-Shaking. All the components are developed from the ground up to be lightweight, responsive, modular and touch friendly.

You can install it from npm using `npm install @syncfusion/ej2-angular-grids --save`

Comment: Your answer should also contain enough information to compare it with gojs, ngx-graph, ej2 (which has been mentioned in comments by @Samaneh) OR tell what's unique in the package which you are suggesting. That would add credibility to your answers and get upvotes.

Answer (score 0):

Try [Dagre](https://github.com/dagrejs/dagre), it can lay out pretty complex graphs, then you can take calculated coordinates and draw them with Angular